# How to use ast.NodeTransformer to transform List Comprehensions to For Loops?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to transform List Comprehensions to For Loops with the help of **ast.NodeTransformer**. After this, I would do a type analysis for Python.

I understand that when an ast node **ast.ListComp** is encountered, it has to be transformed to two ast nodes: the first node is **ast.Assign** and the second is **ast.For**. But according to the document [ast.NodeTransformer](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer), **ast.ListComp** can only be converted into **one** ast node rather than two, which means we can not insert **ast.Assign** and **ast.For** into AST together.

For now I can make an equivalent for loop. But I also need an assignment statement to initialize a list to []. How can I circumvent this problem?

An example may help:

```
a=[x for x in [1,2,3]] # One node in AST
```

to

```
a=[] # One node in AST
for x in [1,2,3]:  # Another one in AST
    a.append(x)
```

Comment: In Python, a generator is a first-class object (with a type); it cannot, in general, be eliminated. You can create one and pass it to a function: `foo(x+2 for x in arr)`. In fact, the equivalent for `[expr for variable in generator]` is to do just that with the built-in list constructor function: `list(expr for variable in generator)`. (And if the `expr` is just the variable, `x for x in...`, you can drop it on the floor: `list(generator)`. I don't know if that actually helps you, though :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively traverse the `AST` and when you encounter a list comprehension (`ast.ListComp`) in an assignment statement, you can remove the parent assignment object and insert into the body scope a standard for-loop that is derived from the comprehension:

```
import ast
def comp_to_expl(tree):
   if hasattr(tree, 'body'):
      i = 0
      while i < len(tree.body):
         if isinstance(a:=tree.body[i], ast.Assign) and isinstance(a.value, ast.ListComp):
            tree.body = tree.body[:i] + \
                [ast.Assign(
                   targets=[ast.Name(id = a.targets[0].id)], value = ast.List(elts = []),
                   lineno = a.lineno
                )] + \
                [ast.For(
                   target = a.value.generators[0].target,
                   iter = a.value.generators[0].iter,
                   body = [ast.Expr(
                             value = ast.Call(
                                       func = ast.Attribute(value = ast.Name(id = a.targets[0].id), attr = 'append', ctx = ast.Load()),
                                       args = [a.value.elt],
                                       keywords = []
                       ))],
                   lineno = a.lineno+1,
                   orelse = [],
                  )] + \
                tree.body[i+1:]   
            i += 1   
         i += 1
   for i in getattr(tree, '_fields', []):
      if isinstance(v:=getattr(tree, i, None), list):
         for i in v: 
            comp_to_expl(i)
      elif isinstance(v, ast.AST):
         comp_to_expl(v)
         
synt = ast.parse('a=[x for x in [1,2,3]]')
comp_to_expl(synt)
print(ast.unparse(synt))
```

Output:

```py
a = []
for x in [1, 2, 3]:
    a.append(x)
```